# simple-peer - Record vidoes for peer to peer calling

Tags: simple-peer

I am planning to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer for peer to peer calling. But in this the two parties get connected without the media server. But I would like to record the conversation. How can I do it? I see that Zencastr is using simple-peer and yet recording the videos. How is it done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) to record video. [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/04/record-almost-everything-in-the-browser-with-mediarecorder/) are some usage examples.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How can I upload it to a server?

Comment: You can find on google how to upload a file to a server